# Valid Parentheses problem programming logic

Tags: python

I am trying to come up with a code for the valid parentheses problem (https://leetcode.com/problems/valid-parentheses/) but I am having trouble understanding the logic of this problem.

This is my pseudocode

1. Iterate over characters in the string.
2. Get the current element.
3. Check if current element is == next element.
   if it is, return true, else return false.

This was my solution but it doesn't work.

```
class Solution(object):
    def isValid(self,s):
        # iterate through the index in the string
        for i in range(0,len(s)-1)):
        # if the current index is equal to the next index, return true
            if(s[i] == s[i+1]):
                return True
```

I asked this question earlier and got the feedback that my code looking for places where the same symbol appears twice in a way. Whereas, I want my code to match up pairs of brackets.

Could someone help me understand the logic of this problem?

Comment: Let Google help you https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/check-for-balanced-parentheses-in-an-expression/

Comment: incidentally why use a class for this?  a simple function is more than enough: there's no *point* hiding the fn in a class

Comment: this is the way leetcode sets every solution.

Comment: Your code returns true for `aa` or `((` or any two matching characters... It doesn't work for **closing brackets** like `{}` or the other examples in the question. It also never returns False. Checking adjacent characters obviously doesn't work for `[()]`

Comment: What you need is a LIFO structure. Which named stack.

Comment: Does my answer work, or am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I would approach it:

```py
class Solution(object):
    def isValid(self, s):
        stack = []
        for char in s:
            if "(" == char:
                stack.append(")")
            elif "{" == char:
                stack.append("}")
            elif "[" == char:
                stack.append("]")
            elif not stack or stack.pop() != char:
                return False
        return not stack
def test_is_valid(s, expected):
    result = is_valid(s)
    print(repr(s), result)
    assert result == expected
is_valid = Solution().isValid
test_is_valid("()", True)
test_is_valid("()[]{}", True)
test_is_valid("(]", False)
test_is_valid("", True)
test_is_valid("{", False)
test_is_valid("}", False)
test_is_valid("[{([])}]", True)
```

Output:

```
'()' True
'()[]{}' True
'(]' False
'' True
'{' False
'}' False
'[{([])}]' True
```